# Editing a resource in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

To begin with, I must say that I am VERY new to Ruby on Rails. I've only been working my way through it for about a week.

I've starting integrating my existing website onto a blog I made which uses two resources - posts and comments.

My problem resides with the posts resource. I made the posts resource using "generate scaffold", to give me the fields "Title" and "Content", however I would now like to add another field "Image", which takes a local url of an image to add to the blog.

I've gone through manually and added references to the new "Image" field, adding it as a string with the intention of using the string as a target in an image_tag when it need to be displayed.
However when I visit pages that use the form to add or edit posts, I'm given the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#new
undefined method `image' for #<Post:0x39a4868>
```

Is there an automated, catch-all way of adding a new field to a pre-existing resource?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip may be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate a migration.

```
rails g migration add_image_to_posts image:string
```

Which will generate a file in db/migrate

You can then run this migration with:

```
rake db:migrate
```

And you should now have an image field in your model.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thanks so much for your help

(... I love RoR :]] )